# How to recover from Solr deleted index files?

Tags: exception, solr

When I delete solr's index files on disk, (found in `/solr/data/index` and `solr/data/spellchecker`), solr throws an exception whenever I try to make a request to it:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/…/solr/data/index:

The only way I've found to recover from this is to “seed” the `data` directory with the index files from elsewhere. It doesn't really matter where it seems. Once I do this, I can run a query to reload the schema and regenerate the index. Is this how this is supposed to work? It seems like there should be a way to tell solr to regenerate those files from scratch. Maybe I'm just mistaken in my assumption that these files are not part of the application itself (kind of implied by the name “data”)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Solr will throw that exception at startup if the `index` directory exists but is empty. However if you delete the directory, Solr will create it and the empty segments files at startup.

Comment: This was my problem, just a note to others, I had to 1) Stop solr, 2) delete the directory, 3) start solr.  When I had solr running and deleted the directory and tried to force an index it would still fail.  Thanks for the help =]

Comment: This is definitely the solution! Good catch :]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sunspot solr on rails, sunspot can reindex all the data from the database into solr. However, solr standalone would not know where to pull the data to reindex. You would need a backup of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie with the segments file  if you delete the index . the files are physically deleted but are present in the ram or cache of the solr . Avoid deleting files directly from solr index files physically . use delete query to delete the index , doing this would alter the segments of the index and you will not have to restart the solr

regards

Rajat

Answer (score 0):

Exception [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed. So either your index is invalid or corrupted.

[NIOFSDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/NIOFSDirectory.html) class is used for reading and writing index files. The directory is created at the named location if it does not yet exist.

So you should probably:

1. Delete the `index` directory or restore data from backups.
2. Restart the server (or at least the reload the config).