# Can't start solr because of missing segment file

Tags: solr, ezpublish

I made a mistake. I downloaded the full data folder from my solr engine to replace the one on my machine. Since this time I can't start solr anymore on my machine.

Here are the main error messages :

```
3865 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1][2015-08-19 10:17:04.742] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  ? Error creating core [ezp-default]: Error opening new searcher
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
```

and

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /whateverFolder/ezpublish_legacy/extension/ezfind/java/solr/ezp-default/data/index/segments_q72
```

This file is actually missing.

I tried different things:

- stop / restart solr
- empty data folder
- event reinstall my cms search plugin

Nothing changed. The error is the same.

One idea I have is that solr start routine is based on a kind of cache or db where it is written "load this segments_q72" file.

Do you have any clue on how to repair this ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938691/how-to-recover-from-solr-deleted-index-files.

Comment: I totally deserve a shame walk. I was not "repairing" in the right folder. The link you gave worked.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested abhishek in the first comment, I found the solution here :

[How to recover from Solr deleted index files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938691/how-to-recover-from-solr-deleted-index-files)

The problem was me. I was not "repairing" in the right folder. My bad.